# Are Javascript strings immutable? Modifying string by str[index] won't affect string but won't generate exception either, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, exception, immutability

The following code doesn't affect string str but won't generate any error or exception either, why?

```
start();

function start(){
  var str = 'abcdef';
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    str[i] = str[i+1];
    console.log(str[i]);
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

The output looks like following:

```
a
b
c
d
e
abcdef
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are immutable.

If you enable strict mode, the silent failures will turn into explicit errors:

```js
'use strict';

start();

function start(){
  var str = 'abcdef';
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    str[i] = str[i+1];
    console.log(str[i]);
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

(Enabling strict mode is generally a good idea, it can make debugging easier)

This isn't a string-specific issue - trying to assign to any read-only property will throw in strict mode, and will fail silently in sloppy mode:

```js
'use strict';
var str = 'a';
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(str, '0'));

const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', { value: 'value' });
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'prop'));
obj.prop = 5;
```